# Reload tableview section without scroll or animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am reloading a tableView section using this code -

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Still the rows replacement is animated and the table view scrolls to the top.

How can I make sure that no animation will be applied to the section reload + prevent the table view from scrolling.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: thanks!...works for me on iOS 10.3, now the section header does not animate

Comment: Thanks,Work for me. But you should enable animation again. UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

Comment: not workig for me endUpdates() crashed. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: `The inserted or deleted rows use the default animations` is what none means

Answer (score 72):

To prevent scrolling and animation, do this:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { 
    let loc = tableView.contentOffset
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    tableView.contentOffset = loc
}
```

Comment: Works for me on iOS9. Amazing technique! Thx

Comment: Docs says .none use the default animation, but with this code updated rows aren't animated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `tableView.setContentOffset(loc, animated: false)` instead of `tableView.contentOffset = loc`

Comment: Worked fo me on Swift 4.1

Comment: the `contentOffset` hack wasn't necessary for me. [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591965/1032372) was sufficient.

Comment: ^ @shim thanks for the info - it might have changed since 2016 and maybe content offset is no longer necessary. There might be edge cases where it matters though.

Answer (score 61):

**Swift 4**:

Actually, the best way to prevent crazy animation during scrolling or expand/collapse cells is:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
       self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: That actually worked and not only on Swift 4 but in 3.2 as well. This API appears to be available since iOS 7.0 Thank you!

Comment: You can skip `self` in `tableView.reloadRows` call to make code little cleaner.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz: You can not remove self since UIView.performWithoutAnimation is a closure. You need to add self inside it

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5**

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
   self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
  }
```

Comment: without UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true) it will still trigger animation of reload

Answer (score 8):

Neither of given answers worked for me.
Here's the solution I found, hope it would be useful to someone

**Swift 4:**

```
let lastScrollOffset = tableView.contentOffset

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()

tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
tableView.setContentOffset(lastScrollOffset, animated: false)
```

Comment: Not working for me, libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 5):

Add one line more to this method in viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
```

Add this code where you want refresh after updation

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 5):

**Objective-C:**

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
   [[self tableView]beginUpdates];
   [self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   [[self tableView]endUpdates];
```

**But I think the following code is more useful and better.**

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{     
                [[self tableView]beginUpdates];
                [self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [[self tableView]endUpdates];
            }];
```

Comment: I think this approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. It seems to stem from putting an IndexPath inside .reloadSections instead of a IndexSet as it requests. Which is why it seems to work with .reloadRows with out issue:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation)

tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet, with: UITableView.RowAnimation)
```

Just wrap the section you want to reload as an IndexSet:

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionInt), with: .none)
```