# How to reload a section header without it disappearing/re-appearing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First off, let me say that I am using a `UITableViewController` with a custom header in my `UITableView`.

My custom header class is defined simply as so:

```
class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var theCountLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I load the custom header class like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! HeaderCell

    if section == 0
    {
        headerCell.theLabel.text = "Test 1"
        headerCell.theCountLabel.text = String(myArrayOne.count)
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        headerCell.theLabel.text = "Test 2"
        headerCell.theCountLabel.text = String(myArrayTwo.count)
    }

    return headerCell.contentView
}
```

Every time I delete a row in my table view from within `editActionsForRowAt`, I call `self.tableView.reloadSections` like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    ...

    var indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet()

    indexSet.insert(indexPath.section)

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        self.myArrayOne.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        self.myArrayTwo.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }

    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    self.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

}
```

Now calling `self.tableView.reloadSections` does work and updates the `theCountLabel` within my section header.

However, I've set `UITableViewRowAnimation` to `none`. But when I scroll further down the `UITableView` pass the current number of visible rows on screen and I delete a row, the section header disappears and reappears with the updated `theCountLabel` value.

I want to always keep my section header on top, i.e. not disappear and re-appear when the section is reloaded.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution referenced by @Abhinav:

[Reload tableview section without scroll or animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33338752/2373410)

Slight modification updated for **Swift 3.0**:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Now if I scroll past the number of visible cells on screen and I delete a row, the `headerCell.theCountLabel.text` in my section header is updated without any animation, and remains still.